# rails: attach some data to "head :ok" response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, http

In rails it is common practice to send a "head :ok" in response to a request. (https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&p=7&q=%22head+%3Aok%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Is it possible to send an json hash along with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to send an json hash along with it?

No.

[`head :ok` sets `render` to return an empty response (so just the header, no body) with status 200.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses)  `head :ok` is shorthand for `render nothing: true, status: :ok`.
 [Here's a list of all the `:status` options you can use for setting the appropriate status code.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option)